# Python matrix diagonal of inf without fill_diagonal

Tags: python, numpy

I need to set the diagonal elements of a matrix to Inf.

An easy way to do it is to use `np.fill_diagonal`.

```
np.fill_diagonal(my_matrix, float('inf')
```

However `fill_diagonal` modifies the input matrix instead of returning a new matrix with the diagonal filled.
This doesn't work for me. I need the diagonals filled WITHOUT modifying the original matrix.

Of course I could clone the original matrix, so I will always keep a copy of the original matrix. However I don't really like this solution, since I will update my original matrix often and therefore I'll have to make copies of it every time I need the diagonal to be inf.

Is there a function that will do the same that `fill_diagonal` but without modifying the input matrix? Something like:

```
new_matrix = np.fill_diagonal(original_matrix, float('inf')
```

**Why I need this:**

My matrix is a distance matrix between points and I want to compute at each step the two closest points. Of course the diagonal of this matrix is 0 (since the distance from a point to itself is 0). So my solution to make sure I don't take the same point is to set the diagonals to Inf.

However once the two points are found, I need to compute the average of the distances between this two points and the rest of the points, so I actually need the diagonals to be 0 instead of Inf.

Currently what I'm doing is:

- Fill diagonals with Inf
- Find the 2 closest points
- Fill diagonals with 0
- Compute the average distance between this two points and the rest of them.

  ```
  # fill diagonal with Inf to avoid taking the diagonals
  np.fill_diagonal(data, float('inf'))  
  # find the minimum distance
  idx = np.argmin(data)
  # fill the diagonals back to 0
  np.fill_diagonal(data, 0.0) 
  # get the coordinates of the minimum distance
  row, col =  np.unravel_index(idx,data.shape)
  # compute the new node as the average distance between the two points
  new_node = np.mean((data[:,row],data[:,col]),0)
  # replace the first node (row) with the new node
  data[:,row] = new_node
  data[row,:] = new_node.T
  # delete the second node (col) from the matrix
  data = np.delete(data, col, 0)  # delete row
  data = np.delete(data, col, 1)  # delete column
  ```

However I don't like the idea of setting diagonals to Inf and then back to 0, I would prefer just passing a function to `argmax` that returns data with diagonal  filled with Inf without actually modifying the matrix data.

Something like:

```
idx = np.argmin(return_filled_diagonals(data, float('Inf'))
# here I can operate with data as usual since it has not been modified.
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that correctly: You want a new matrix with the diagonal filled but you don't want to make a copy because you update it often? How exactly should that work? Do you have a use-case? Where and when (any special functions that need that?) do you need the diagonal to be filled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
orig_mat = np.array([[1.2,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

#set diagonal to inf without making a copy of the array.
orig_mat + np.where(np.eye(orig_mat.shape[0])>0,np.inf,0)
array([[ inf,   2.,   3.],
       [  4.,  inf,   6.],
       [  7.,   8.,  inf]])

#the original array remains untorched.
print(orig_mat)
[[ 1.2  2.   3. ]
 [ 4.   5.   6. ]
 [ 7.   8.   9. ]]
```

Comment: This will indeed work. Using a mask to be added to the original matrix only when calling `np.argmin` looks good to me.

Comment: This ends up making three (temporary) arrays the size of `orig_mat`, the results of the `eye`, the `where` and the `sum`.  I suspect a simple function that makes a copy and fills it will be faster (more efficient).

Answer (score 4):

**Approach #1**

The magic you are looking for is in [`NumPy strides`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) that gets us a view of the array without the diagonal elements and as such doesn't occupy anymore of the memory space. Here's the implementation to get such a view -

```
def nodiag_view(a):
    m = a.shape[0]
    p,q = a.strides
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a[:,1:], (m-1,m), (p+q,q))
```

Let's take a look at a sample run to verify that its a view -

```
In [124]: a  # Input array
Out[124]: 
array([[ 0, 61, 43, 26, 21],
       [20,  0, 78, 29, 64],
       [34, 49,  0, 64, 60],
       [36, 96, 67,  0, 75],
       [36, 85, 40, 74,  0]])

# Get the no-diag view
In [125]: a_nodiag = nodiag_view(a)

# Lets's verify by changing elements in the view and that should change
# elements in the original array too
In [126]: a_nodiag[:] = 999

In [127]: a
Out[127]: 
array([[  0, 999, 999, 999, 999],
       [999,   0, 999, 999, 999],
       [999, 999,   0, 999, 999],
       [999, 999, 999,   0, 999],
       [999, 999, 999, 999,   0]])
```

Finally, let's see how we can setup it up to solve your entire problem -

```
def argmin_without_diag(a):
    a_nodiag = nodiag_view(a)
    idx_nodiag = np.argmin(a_nodiag)
    m = a.shape[0]
    idx = idx_nodiag + np.unravel_index(idx_nodiag, (m-1,m))[0]+1
    return  np.unravel_index(idx, a.shape)
```

Sample run -

```
In [142]: a
Out[142]: 
array([[ 0, 60, 79, 55, 77],
       [62,  0, 86, 84, 25],
       [32, 96,  0, 74, 89],
       [24, 33, 64,  0, 93],
       [14, 74, 30, 44,  0]])

In [143]: argmin_without_diag(a)
Out[143]: (4, 0)
```

---

**Approach #2**

If you worry about both memory and performance, you could temporarily set the diagonal ones as `infnite`, then get the `argmin` index and then put back the original diagonal values. Thus, effectively the input array is unchanged. The implementation would look something like this -

```
def argmin_without_diag_replacement(a):
    # Store diagonal values
    vals = a.ravel()[::a.shape[1]+1].copy()

    # Set diag ones as infinites
    a.ravel()[::a.shape[1]+1] = np.inf

    # Get argmin index
    idx = np.argmin(a)

    # Put back the original diag values
    a.ravel()[::a.shape[1]+1] = vals
    return np.unravel_index(idx, a.shape)
```

Thus, for `(n x n)` shaped array, the temporary array would have just `n` elements.

Sample run -

```
In [237]: a
Out[237]: 
array([[  0.,  95.,  57.,  75.,  92.],
       [ 37.,   0.,  69.,  71.,  62.],
       [ 42.,  72.,   0.,  30.,  57.],
       [ 41.,  80.,  94.,   0.,  26.],
       [ 36.,  45.,  71.,  76.,   0.]])

In [238]: argmin_without_diag_replacement(a)
Out[238]: (3, 4)
```

**Runtime test**

```
In [271]: a = np.random.randint(11,99,(1000,1000)).astype(float)

In [272]: np.fill_diagonal(a,0)

In [273]: %timeit argmin_without_diag(a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.76 ms per loop

In [274]: %timeit argmin_without_diag_replacement(a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 688 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to find the index of the min of the matrix, but not include the diagonal elements:

```
orig_mat = np.array([[1.2,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
min_idx = np.argmin(orig_mat+np.multiply(np.eye(orig_mat.shape[0]),1e9))
```

Comment: But here you are also modifying x and setting the diagonal elements to Inf. I need to return a new matrix y that is basically the matrix x with inf diagonals keeping the original matrix x untouched

Comment: Yes, but you are still making a copy of the matrix and saving it to a variable. I just want to pass the result of setting the diagonals to Inf to the function argmin and then not using this matrix anymore, so no need to make a copy, storing it to a variable, etc...  It's just for efficiency.

Comment: Ok, now I think I understand -- one last try. See my edits.

Comment: Sorry, `multiply` will not work with `Inf` since `0*Inf` is undetermined. And 
 using a big number `1e9` it's not a good solution since distances might be arbitrarily large. Anyway there's already one answer which will work, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

My nomination is the explicit copy and fill, wrapped in a function

```
def foo(mat):
    a = mat.copy()
    np.fill_diagonal(a,np.inf)
    return a
```

This does make a copy, but only one.

```
orig_mat + np.where(np.eye(orig_mat.shape[0])>0,np.inf,0))
```

returns a new array as well,but in the process has to make two added temporary ones.  So it ends up being slower:

for `orig_mat=np.ones((1000,1000))`

```
In [67]: timeit np.argmin(orig_mat + np.where(np.eye(orig_mat.shape[0])>0, np.inf, 0))
100 loops, best of 3: 18.7 ms per loop
In [68]: timeit np.argmin(foo(orig_mat))
100 loops, best of 3: 6.94 ms per loop
```

Surprisingly `@Divakar's` solution isn't much faster:

```
In [69]: timeit argmin_without_diag(orig_mat)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.97 ms per loop
```

Comment: Added another one with focus on performance, though I wasn't sure if OP was going for performance the first time around.