# How to calculate the relative vectors from a list of points, from one point to every other point

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of points in `(x,y)` pairs, which represents the positions of a list of agents. For example, given 3 agents, there are 3 pairs of points, which I store as follows:

```
points = np.array([[x1, y1],
                   [x2, y2],
                   [x3, y3]])
```

I would like to calculate a subsequent array, that is the relative position from one agent to every other agent, but NOT itself. So, using the data above, I would like to generate the array `relative_positions` using the array `points`. `points` can have `N` positions (I can have upwards of 50-100 agents at any one time).

So using `points` described above, I would like to produce the output:

```
relative_positions = [[x2-x1, y2-y1],
                      [x3-x1, y3-y1],
                      [x1-x2, y1-y2],
                      [x3-x2, y3-y2],
                      [x1-x3, y1-y3],
                      [x2-x3, y2-y3]]
```

For example, given four agent positions stored as a numpy array:

```
agent_points = np.array([[10, 1],
                         [30, 3],
                         [25, 10],
                         [5, 5]])
```

I would like to generate the output:

```
relative_positions = [[30-10,  3-1],
                      [25-10, 10-1],
                      [5-10,   5-1],
                      [10-30,  1-3],
                      [25-30, 10-3],
                      [5-30,   5-3],
                      [10-25, 1-10],
                      [30-25, 3-10],
                      [5-25,  5-10],
                      [10-5,   1-5],
                      [30-5,   3-5],
                      [25-5,  10-5]]
```

How do I effectively go about doing this? I have thought about just calculating every difference possible, and removing the 0 cases (for when it's the relative position from the agent to itself), however I do not think that is a "pure" way to do it, since I could accidentally remove an agent that just happens to be on exactly the same point (or very close to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

With `a` the input array, you can do -

```
d = (a-a[:,None,:])
valid_mask = ~np.eye(len(a),dtype=bool)
out = d[valid_mask]
```

Basically, we are extending `a` to `3D` such that first axis is made `outer-broadcastable` and then we perform subtraction against its `2D` version, resulting in `mxmx2` shaped output, with `m` being the `a.shape[0]`. Schematically put -

```
a[:, None, :]    :  4 x 1 x 2
a                :      4 x 2
output           :  4 x 4 x 2
```

[`More info`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Another way to create `valid_mask`, would be -

```
r = np.arange(len(a))
valid_mask = r[:,None] != r
```

**Approach #2**

We will leverage `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` to get a no-diagonal mask for `3D` arrays (along first two axes), so that we will use it here to mask the differences array `d`. This mask generation is inspired by a `2D` array problem as posted [**`here`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43761941/) and for a`3D` case would look something like this -

```
def nodiag_view3D(a):
    m = a.shape[0]
    p,q,r = a.strides
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a[:,1:], shape=(m-1,m,2), strides=(p+q,q,r))
```

To solve our problem, it would be -

```
d = (a-a[:,None,:])
out = nodiag_view3D(d).reshape(-1,a.shape[1])
```

---

#### Timings to showcase how approach#2 improves upon #1

```
In [96]: a = np.random.rand(5000,2)

In [97]: d = (a-a[:,None,:])

In [98]: %%timeit
    ...: valid_mask = ~np.eye(len(a),dtype=bool)
    ...: out = d[valid_mask]
1 loop, best of 3: 763 ms per loop

In [99]: %%timeit
    ...: r = np.arange(len(a))
    ...: valid_mask = r[:,None] != r
    ...: out = d[valid_mask]
1 loop, best of 3: 767 ms per loop

In [100]: %timeit nodiag_view3D(d).reshape(-1,a.shape[1])
10 loops, best of 3: 177 ms per loop
```

Comment: That's a very elegant solution. I understand most of what is happening, could you please explain what the `a[:,None,:] `does in this case?

Comment: @Athena Added some comments.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have a numpy specific solution (I'm sure it exists) a double for-loop and id check can do the trick just fine. It'll need some time if `points` grows, though.

```py
points = [
    [x1, y1],
    [x2, y2],
    [x3, y3]
]

relative_positions = []
for point1 in points:
    for point2 in point:
        if id(point1) != id(point2):
            relative_positions.append([CALC_HERE_OR_FUNCTION])
```

Comment: Thanks, I had considered this option, however I am probably looking for numpy specific solution, since I'm concerned with speed (this calculation can be performed between 100k-10M times per episode